# Jquery Lazyload - Callback not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I am using the jQuery Lazyload plugin from https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload like this..

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

jQuery("img.lazyload").lazyload({
       load : function()
    {
        console.log("dddd"); // Callback here
    }
});
});
```

But the load function does not appear to be working, I am expecting to get dddd in the console log when a new image is loaded but I get nothing.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as far as I can tell (you didn't provide any html so I can't be positive).  I did some troubleshooting and discovered the API you are attempting to utilize only works with lazyload versions under version 2.  I tested it specifically with lazyload version 1.9.7 - the current 'release' version.

You will have to download the source code, version 1.9.7 from github, and include the `jquery.lazyload.min.js` file into your project.

Comment: I am loading the image in a modal popup, maybe this is having an effect

Comment: Have you tested it with version 1.9.7? With version 2+ your code will not work as the API has been updated and does not include that callback functionality.